# How do I set the status of a Script Assertion in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

After looking at [this](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/3.0.0/soapui/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/assertions/basic/GroovyScriptAssertion.html) documentation, GroovyScriptAssertion (SoapUI 3.0.0 API) (smartbear.com), I've tried the following

```
def currentStep = context.getCurrentStep();
def assertion = currentStep.getAssertionByName('Script Assertion');
assertion.setStatus(com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable.AssertionStatus.FAILED);
```

but I get the error

```
setStatus() exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.GroovyScriptAssertion.setStatus() is applicable for argument types: (com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable$AssertionStatus) values: [FAILED]
```

If I output

```
assertion.getClass()
```

It tells me that assertion's class is

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.GroovyScriptAssertion@71d72a30
```

And this documentation says that the groovyScriptAssertion class has a method called getStatus on it
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/3.0.0/soapui/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/assertions/basic/GroovyScriptAssertion.html

which it inherits from wsdlMessageAssertion
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/3.0.0/soapui/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlMessageAssertion.html#setStatus-com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable.AssertionStatus-

and takes an assertionStatus object as a parameter
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/3.0.0/soapui/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/Assertable.AssertionStatus.html

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using 5.7.1

Edit:

If it's not possible to set the status of a test assertion or test step, is it possible to set the status of a testCase?

Comment: If the assertion is done properly in the `Script Assertion`, you won't run into this situation. So, please explain the use case. What is in script assertion as well?